# Data from Google Drive's Appdata folder is disappearing

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to create Spreadsheet file in Google Drive's Appdata folder for my aplication, to use it as a remote database.

Just at the beggining and I'm stuck already. Files are created properly(?), but they seems to be dissapearing after a moment.

I'm doing it like this:

1. First, on onCreate method I log into my Google Account:

   ```
   GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
           .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
           .requestEmail()
           .build();
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
           .enableAutoManage(this, this)
           .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
           .addApi(Drive.API)
           .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
           .build();

   signIn();

   private void signIn() {
   Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
   startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
   }
   ```
2. onActivityResult handles updating UI(displaying user's name and profile pic, all works great on the login/logout side)
3. Then, in onConnected(Bundle bundle) method, I try to find out if user already has existing database in AppFolder, if not, I'm asking him to create one.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
   queryDrive();
   }

   public void queryDrive() {
   Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, DreamDbSchema.NAME_REMOTE)).build();

   Drive.DriveApi.query(mGoogleApiClient, query).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
       @Override
       public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult) {
           MetadataBuffer buffer = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer();

           if (buffer != null) {
               if (buffer.getCount() == 0) {
                   new AlertDialog.Builder(ListActivity.this).setTitle(R.string.no_database_on_gdrive)
                           .setMessage(R.string.no_database_on_gdrive_message)
                           .setCancelable(false)
                           .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                               }
                           })
                           .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                   Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
                               }
                           })
                           .setNeutralButton(R.string.cancel_and_disconnect, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                   signOut();
                               }
                           })
                           .show();
               } else {
                   for (int i = 0; i < buffer.getCount(); i++) {
                       Log.d("DRIVE_FILES: ", buffer.get(i).getTitle());
                   }
               }
           } else {
               Log.d("DRIVE_BUFFER: ", "null");
           }
       }
   });
   }

   final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
       new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
           @Override
           public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
               if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                   Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, R.string.error_while_creating_GDrive_file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   return;
               }

               MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                       .setTitle(DreamDbSchema.NAME_REMOTE)
                       .setMimeType("vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet")
                       .build();
               Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                       .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, result.getDriveContents())
                       .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
           }
       };


   final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
       ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
           @Override
           public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
               if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                   Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, R.string.error_while_creating_GDrive_file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   return;
               }
               Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, getString(R.string.database_created_GD), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       };
   ```
4. Everything seems to be working good for about 10 minutes. In another activity I can successfully remove this file like this:

   ```
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
               Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, R.string.not_loged_in, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           } else {
               Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient).listChildren(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResult(final DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult) {
                           Log.d("DRIVE_FILES: ", String.valueOf(metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer().getCount()));
                       for (int i = 0; i < metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer().getCount(); i++) {
                           final int j = i;
                           DriveId fileId = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer().get(i).getDriveId();
                           Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient, fileId).delete(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onResult(Status status) {
                                   if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                       Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, R.string.database_removed_GD, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   }
                               }
                           });
                       }
                   }
               });
           }
       }
   ```

and it also prints in log "1" for a while. But give it a ten minutes or so, and I'm once again prompted to create database, because it finds Appdata folder to be empty.

Comment: Does the same issue occur when you try with [this sample](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileInAppFolderActivity.java). The sample is for creating files in the App Folder.

Comment: I've performed some tests with your link and changing appfolder for rootfolder, to get some better visibility, and it looks, like the problem is somewhere in the mimetype. I can create and delete text/plain files without a problem, but It's not creating spreadsheets. When I have it as "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" I get an exception "This method may not be used to create Google Apps files." Without "application" part, it's not creating anything.

Comment: Currently the GDAA does not support the creation of Google Drive files like spreadsheets. You can use the REST API to do that.